# Why CSS Submenu fails on Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm new to programming web and I made this small submenu and works properly in Mozilla, but in IE when I run the submenu disappears.

Why is this only happens in IE?

I use IE11

**Code**:

http://jsfiddle.net/4nLabpon/

or:

```
<div id="grad1">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu-holder">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="active">
                    <a class="test" href="#">Planning</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="">Add Products</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Add Clients</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="">Deadline</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Sells</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- menu-holder end -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grad1 {
    height: auto;
    background-color: grey;
}   
.wrapper {
     width:600px;
     height:30px;
     opacity:0.9;
     margin:0 auto;
 }
 .menu-holder ul {
     margin: 2px 0 0px 25px;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 100px 0px;
     border-left: 1px dotted white;
     line-height: 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:hover > a {
     background-color: #1b597d;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li a {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul {
     float: none;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 0px;
     margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul:hover {
     display: block;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li {
     position: static;
     float: none;
     display: inline;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
     background-color: #1b597d;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li a {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-weight: normal;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:first-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:last-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
     border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:first-of-type {
     border-left: none;
 }
```

Thank you all

Comment: Works for me on IE9, Windows 7.

Comment: I try on IE version 11.0.9600 fails :(

Comment: For me it also fails. The submenu does not persist when you hover over it. I am about to crack it (IE 11)

Comment: `:hover` is only supported on links in most IE versions. You use it in an LI. <-- Ignore it, this is your problem: `.menu-holder ul li ul:hover` - the `:hover`is on the hidden `ul`, which won't work. Change the selector to `.menu-holder ul li:hover ul`.

Comment: If you are bored while i watch it, see on a page I made: http://orywahl.de works on IE11 trying to copy the structure

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I tried the change that you said, but still doesn't working :(

Comment: I can tell you what happens you somewhere put a padding or so on the li and it pushes away under the mouse pointer

Comment: Your whole problem comes from a `position: absolute` and lots of work with `margin`, `top`, `left` to make it look like you expect, just because of this positioning. Getting rid of all of this, you're nearly there: http://jsfiddle.net/4nLabpon/1/

Comment: If i put the mouse over menu, the submenu shows correctly, but when I try put the mouse over submenu this disappears.

Comment: Holy, I was about to do that but that was too much fiddle glad you are there going gaming in the web now ;) @MelanciaUK

Comment: @MelanciaUK But exists a litle problem. The menu expands and disrupts everything.

Comment: As I said, you're nearly there. If I've fixed the issue, I would have posted an answer, not a comment. :) I'm running out of time now. I'll come back later and crack on if nobody posts an answer.

Comment: @rpirez I used MelanciaUK's answer and fixed it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/4nLabpon/2/ (I just removed the positions,floats and changed margins on `.menu-holder ul li ul` and changed from `display:block;` to `display:table;` on `.menu-holder ul li ul:hover`)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel i tried your code, but in Internet Explorer 11 continuous failing :S

Comment: @rpirez You should reinstall windows. It's working fine (I have windows 8.1, so, it uses IE11). Check here: http://i57.tinypic.com/vnf3fl.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="active"><a class="test" href="#">Planning</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="">Add Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Add Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Deadline</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sells</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css Style :

```
.wrapper{
float:left;
width:100%;
position:relative;
background:#0066CC;
color:#fff;
}

ul.menu{
float:left;
width:100%;
list-style:none;
color:#000000;
}

ul li a{
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
padding:5px;
}

ul.menu li{
display:inline-block;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
background:#cccccc;
color:#ff6600;
}

ul.menu li > ul{
float:left;
position:absolute;
width:auto;
margin-top:0px;
left:0px;
display:none;
}

ul.menu li > ul li{
    margin:0;
}

ul.menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```